# How long have people been swearing in English?

Tags: etymology, offensive-language, neologisms

I was looking through my old A-Level English set books from 1989 at the weekend. We had to study the Canterbury Tales and I can still remember our delight when we discovered that 'queynte' was the 13th Century form of a certain four-letter obscenity beginning with 'c', used to describe the female regenerative organs.

Unlike its modern counterpart, 'queynte' was not, it seems, an obscenity back in Chaucer's time. I was wondering if anyone knew when it morphed into 'c*nt' and became a taboo word. And, by extension, the earliest usages of it and 'f*ck' as obscene, taboo and/or abusive words. Off the top of my head, I seem to recall reading somewhere that the earliest example of the eff-word is in Lady Chatterley's Lover, but I may be mistaken.

Also, I know a lot of swearing in our times is based on what are referred to as 'Anglo Saxon' words/usages. Why is this? And were the Angles and Saxons a ruder lot than the Vikings?

UPDATE:

From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunt)

The word in its modern meaning is attested in Middle English. Proverbs of Hendyng, a manuscript from some time before 1325, includes the advice:[9]

> 'Ȝeue þi cunte to cunnig and craue affetir wedding.'
>   (*Trans*:  Give your cunt wisely and make (your) demands after the wedding." )

So it would appear it was acceptable at least around the 13th/14th century.

Comment: All my life....

Comment: All my life too! for some reason this question seems to be similar to "how long have people had sex?" And the only answer is "duh"

Comment: Not really no, I'm asking when apparently 'respectable' words fell out of favour and become taboo/obscene. Probably some time before you and @Sam were born.

Comment: What makes you think that 'queynte' was not an obscenity back in Chaucer's time?

Comment: That's an interesting point. I wish we had quizzed our tutor about it instead of sniggering at the back of the class.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland - please see my update to the OP.

Comment: For ‘cunt’, see also ‘quim’, whose earliest attested citation in the OED is from 1613, where it was spelled ‘queme’. They don’t know where it came from.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The use of *fuck* as an expletive and *cunt* as a term of abuse date only from the early twentieth century. *Fuck* itself is first recorded as a verb in 1528 and as a noun in 1663. *Cunt* is considerably earlier, the OED’s oldest citation being the name of the street in London once known as *Gropecuntelane*.

Both words have Germanic origins and were not taboo words to begin with. What might have happened is that, following the Norman Conquest, French words for bodily parts and fuctions took the place of the Old English equivalents in respectable contexts, leaving the Old English words to be used in less respectable ones.

As for swearing generally, it seems likely that there have always been taboo words, but that their nature has varied. Some research has suggested that swearing is processed in a different part of the brain from other language. It’s a fascinating topic which can’t be covered adequately in a few lines here.

Comment: Prejudice against Anglo-Saxons.

Comment: The poor women of that street..

Comment: "Why god hates German words" http://techno-anthropology.blogspot.com/2011/07/why-god-hates-german-words.html?

Comment: @Barrie there were taboo words until the 20C, they were anything blasphemous. Names for natural bodily functions aren't inherently bad, but "Taking the name of the Lord in Vain" is (at least according to the Lord in question!)

Comment: @onomatomaniak - the name of the street was normally advertising the services of the rather prosperous women of the street. A euphemism is "Threadneedle" street - now the home of the Bank of England

Comment: @MartinBeckett, Yes, I'm sure being a prostitute in the 17th century was awesome.

Comment: @MartinBeckett: Indeed. I was going to say so, and not only in the case of the Christian religion, but I didn't want to make my answer any longer.

Comment: @MartinBeckett: I’d not heard that Threadneedle Street was a euphemism for anything. Do you have a source? ‘Brewer’s Dictionary of Phrase and Fable’ says, ‘The name first appears as “Three needle Street” in 1598, and previously it seems to have been called “Broad Street”, forming part of the present “Old Broad Street”. The name is usually said to derive from a signboard with three needles on it, or from the arms of the Needle-makers’ Company; but it may derive from the children’s game of thread-the-needle having been played there.’

Comment: @Barrie - Seamstress is a common euphemism for ladies who "earn their keep by the prick of a (different) needle" (Henry V?). I thought threadneedle street was what the previous alleys were sometimes renamed to - I don't know if that's true for the specific one in London

Comment: @MartinBeckett - +1 for this week's Best Use of a Shakespeare (?) quote :-)

Answer (score 1):

People have been swearing in English as long as there has been English.

The swearwords have changed a lot depending on which words have been effective to use in that way. Today they are often related to sex, earlier in history they were often related to religion, like for example *damned*.

Comment: And one of the most common ways to avoid swearing is to use a euphemism. Or a foreign equivalent: either the proper version or the swearing version.